# Split string in one cell to multiple row with specific column from multiple cell in 1 row

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, split

Datagridview Form1 Bill: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHq0V.jpg

```
ProductName            |  Amount | 
Cocacola,Pepsi,TeaTH   |  1,2,3  |
```

I have one row represent receipt from one customer(one receipt stored multiple name of product, amount each product,.. split by ',' in one cell), when double click to datagridview it will pass data to form2 and display as full detail.

I want to split ProductName, Amount into multiple row like this.

Datagridview Form2 Bill:

```
ProductName   |  Amount | 
Cocacola      |  1      | 
Pepsi         |  2      | 
Tea           |  3      |
```

This is the closet result i can get

```
    *Form 1:*
       public static string ProductName= "";
       public static string ProductAmount= "";
    
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
       {
             ProductName= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
             ProductAmount= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       }
    }
    *Form 2:* 
    
            string StringProductName = Form1.ProductName;
            string StringProductAmmout = Form1.ProductAmount;
    
            string[] item1 = StringProductName .Split(',');
            string[] item2 = StringProductAmmout .Split(',');
    
            foreach (string x in item1)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = x;
    
                foreach (string x2 in item2 )
                {
                  dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = x2;
                }
    
            }

    Result: 
    ProductName   |  Amount | 
    Cocacola      |  3      | 
    Pepsi         |  3      | 
    Tea           |  3      |
```

The amount column is incorrect, it must be 1, 2, 3.
Hope someone can give me an idea or any other method to solve this problem, thank you!.

Comment: use `for` instead of `foreach` so you can take the amount value by it's index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it, use foreach for each cell.

```
    int index = 0;
    foreach (string x in item1)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = x;
        index++;
    }

    int index1 = 0;
    foreach (string x2 in item2)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[index1].Cells[1].Value = x2;
        index1++;
    }
```